# Click on typescript error message in integrated terminal using vscode on Windows

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I noticed that when running vscode on Mac OS-X, that I can click on a typescript error that is displayed in the integrated terminal (we're running typescript in watch mode, using webpack and awesome-typescript-loader). vscode will then automatically navigate to the correct file and line number. Very handy.

However, this doesn't seem to work on Windows. Does anyone know why and how to get the same behavior?

Or maybe better ways exist than running webpack/awesome-typescript-loader in the integrated terminal, maybe it can become a vscode task, that provides errors to the IDE?

Thanks a lot,
Peter

- VSCode Version: Code 1.13.0 (376c52b955428d205459bea6619fc161fc8faacf, 2017-06-08T16:43:13.058Z)
- OS Version: Windows_NT ia32 10.0.14393
- Extensions: none